# Numpy array to tolist is very slow

Tags: python, performance, numpy, netcdf, memory-efficient

I am reading NetCDF file and converting that to GeoJSON. Functionality is completed, but it's taking around 40 seconds to complete the execution. Any way to optimize this code. This may be due to the three for loops and tolist convertion of numpy array on three different locations.

```
import time
import geobuf
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from collections import OrderedDict

def main():
    '''
    The main method that holds the logic for conversion
    '''
    dataset = Dataset('outfile.nc', 'r')

    data_dict = OrderedDict({
        'type': 'FeatureCollection',
        'features': []
    })

    for traj in range(dataset.variables['trajectory'].size):
        for t in range(dataset.variables['time'].size):
            lat = dataset.variables['lat'][traj, t].tolist()
            lon = dataset.variables['lon'][traj, t].tolist()

            if lat is None or lon is None:
                continue
            feature_dict = OrderedDict({
                'type': 'Feature',
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'Point',
                    'coordinates': [lat, lon]
                },
                'properties': {}
            })
            for var in dataset.variables.keys():
                if var not in ['lon', 'lat', 'time', 'trajectory']:
                    dvar = dataset.variables[var]
                    feature_dict['properties'][var] = dvar[traj, t].tolist()
            data_dict['features'].append(feature_dict)
    
    # This encoding is not slow
    pbf = geobuf.encode(data_dict)
    print(pbf)

    dataset.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    '''
    Entrypoint to this script
    '''
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Generally I've found that `arr.tolist()` is pretty fast.  But `dataset.variables['lat'][traj, t].tolist()` might also include the file read time.  I'm not sure about NETCDF4, but the `dataset` in `h5py` is an object on the file, to make an array it needs to be 'fetched', e.g. `dataset[:]`.

Comment: if @hpaulj is correct, it is probably a good idea to load the whole file in memory (if the file is small enough). What is the average number of `traj`, of `t` and `var` in this case?